# Stuck on "Importing Gradle project" during sync on Canary 13

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose development. I tried to start new Empty Compose Activity, but when I start it, keeps getting stuck on "Importing Gradle project".

[image]

Comment: Why you can't just use a stable version?

Comment: @MartinZeitler - Jetpack Compose is only supported in Canary versions of Android Studio (given that itself is only in alpha).

Comment: Nothing concrete but this works for most issues:  1) Delete the contents of the build directory 2) Invalidate Caches and Restart Android Studio. 3) Build Gradle

Comment: @MartinZeitler I just wants to try Jetpack Compose

Comment: @2jan222 you mean the whole build Gradle?

Comment: @FadelFarinsqi Normal Build of the app, Gradle build task

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling the Android Studio